# Kotlin: How can I pass a predicate to CharSequence.any() function?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to find whether a character belongs to a string.

```
var s = "abcdef"
var result = s.any('d')
```

But I can't understand that syntax. From [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/any.html):

```
fun CharSequence.any(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Boolean
```

How can I pass a predicate to the function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Full syntax:

```
s.any({ ch -> ch == 'd' })
```

We can make some simplifications.

First, since lambda parameter comes last, we can place it outside of the parentheses and omit them entirely, when there is no more parameters left.

Second, for lambda function literal with one parameter it is possible to omit the parameter declaration and reference that parameter by `it` name.

Thus the simplified equivalent would be:

```
s.any { it == 'd' }
```

Comment: For more information please see http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html